# jquery looping question

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am in the the each() loop of a given `<tr>` on my page.  How do I loop through all the `<th>` within `$(this)` i.e. within the current `<tr>`:

```
$('#my_table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
   // how to loop through all the <th>'s inside the current tr?
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#my_table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
   $('th', this).each( ... );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do this in the original loop:

```
$('#my_table > tbody > tr > th').each(function() {
```

but if you can't do that for some reason, like there is other code in the loop, you can use this:

```
$('th',this).each(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find('th').each(...)
```

OR

```
$('th', this).each(...)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$('#my_table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
  $(this).filter('th').each(function(){
   //your code here
   });
});
```

but it can be done more concisely if you don't need to perform any operations on the `tr` or can chain them.

Comment: `filter` will remove any elements from the _current_ selector that aren't `th`, rather than get children that are `th`